# Trying to add a library to Symfony using composer

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to add the following library ([link](https://github.com/jaggedsoft/php-binance-api)) to my Symfony project using composer.

I have run

> composer require jaggedsoft/php-binance-api

without a problem but I am getting the following error when loading the page.

> Attempted to load class "API" from namespace "App\Controller\Binance".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

```
public function index(){
   require '../vendor/autoload.php';
   $api = new Binance\API("<api key>","<secret>");
}
```

Now i am guessing that I need to add a use statement but I am a bit stuck on what it is that I need to add.

Comment: you could either prefix it with \ so `new \Binance\Api` or use use statements as suggested by php ^^ apparently just adding a `use Binance` after your namespace might be sufficient.

Comment: If I add "use App\Controller\Binance;" I still get the same error message

Comment: the point is, your file has the namespace `App\Controller` so everything not defined otherwise is assumed to live in that namespace. `Binance\API` for example does not.

Comment: The require vendor/autoload statement goes at the very top of the very first file loaded.  You would not put it inside a method call. Nothing to do with namespaces or use statements.

Comment: @Cerad, I have checked the index.php file and it does already include a require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php'; So I have taken that line out but Im still getting Attempted to load class "API" from namespace "App\Controller\Binance".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Comment: I am wondering if I need to add or declare something somewhere else within the framework.

Comment: Managed to solve it, I needed to include "use Binance;" at the top of the file

Comment: Glad you got it working.  I'm guessing that the code you posted in your question: new Binance\API(); was actually just new API();  Hence the need for a use statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reiterate what I suggested in the comments (options 1 and 3 below):

The namespace of your file - although not explicitly written in your post - is:

```
App\Controller
```

without any `use` statement, the `new Binance\API(...)` is interpreted as:

```
App\Controller\Binance\API
```

which is the concatenation of `App\Controller` (your namespace)  and `Binance\API` (the classname used).

which of course is not what you want to use, since this is something you tried to include from the binance package. This also explains the error message

> Attempted to load class `API` from namespace `App\Controller\Binance`. Did you forget a `use` statement for another namespace?

which is exactly what went wrong. PHP tried to load `App\Controller\Binance\API` which is class `API` from namespace `App\Controller\Binance`.

Now there are A few different ways to fix this:

1. add `use Binance;` in the header of your file, then you can use `new Binance\API(...)`
2. add `use Binance\API;` in the header of your file, then you can use `new API(...)`
3. don't add a `use` statement, then you can use `new \Binance\APi(...)`
4. add `use Binance as Something;` in the header of your file, then you can use `new Something\API(...);` (aliasing the parent namespace `Binance` as `Something` may resolve name collisions)
5. add `use Binance\API as BinanceApi;` in the header of your file, then you can use `new BinanceApi(...);`

You decided to use option 1. Which is preferable, if the class (`API` in this case) isn't very expressive or unique on its own - so is option 5. However, if you use more classes from the `Binance` namespace, option 1 is preferable.

Option 3 will *always* work (and might seem preferable if any of the other options seem overkill for some reason) - you can actually get by without any `use` statement at all, but it can get frustrating to read and write.

Overall, all options are viable and it comes to taste which one to use. Mixing those options may lead to confusion. Inside Symfony I've mostly seen option 2 with the occasional alias (`use ... as ...;`), especially when using DoctrineORM annotations or when extending some Class which has the same Class name but in a different namespace:

```
namespace [package1];

use [package2]\[ClassName] as Base[ClassName];

class [ClassName] extends Base[ClassName] { ... }
```

I hope this explanation helps. The php docs for namespaces are actually helpful, when you understand the core concept of namespaces.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this, it helps a lot